# how to design the DB table and Class?

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns, database-design

Following is a table structure in my system. The scenario is, system has Clients. Clients can be 
many type, for exampel: a Person, a Company, a Bank or etc. I have come with a database design as follows.

**TABLE : CLIENT**

```
===============================
| ID    | NAME_CODE | TYPE    |
-------------------------------
| 1000  | Martin    | PERSON  |
| 1002  | George    | PERSON  |
| 1003  | Max_Group | COMPANY |
-------------------------------
```

**TABLE : PERSON**

```
==================================================
|  ID | CLIENT_ID  | FIRST_NAME   | LAST_NAME    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1   | 1001       | Martin       | XXXXXXXXXXX  |
| 2   | 1002       | George       | XXXXXXXXXXX  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**TABLE : COMPANY**

```
===================================================
| ID | CLIENT_ID  | NAME           | Location     |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1003       | Max Group Inc. | XXXXXXXXXXX  |
---------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT : ID added for PERSON and COMPANY tables.

I welcome if any one could suggest me a better structure.

For the above structure, I need to creat the class model. Following is what I have created.

```
class Client
{
   int ID;
   string NameCode;
}

class Person : Client
{
    int ID;
    int ClientId;
    string FirstName;
    stirng LastName;
    //........
}

class Company : Client
{
    int ID;
    int ClientId;
    string Name;
    string Location;
    //.........
}
```

I feel the above model are not suitable. There can be a right way for this. 
Please suggest me a better way.

Comment: is the number of types of clients variable? Like would you have something else added besides person, bank and company?

Comment: No. it is fixed at design time itself.

Comment: In that case why do you want a client table at all?

Comment: Yes, there are number of types of clients. At the end all are client. I need to maintain a specific ID for all client and they should be able to reference in other activities in other tables. ex: another tale named 'JOB_REQUEST' it will have the reference to client (ClientId). Using this reference I should be able to load the correct model of it. You can suggest a better way.

Comment: Muneer, in the end they all are different objects for you. They can be all clients but thats for application logic. Why would u want to have a common id field for them? My idea is to have separate id for them. To ensure different id for `person` and `bank` from your db side is more work (may even slow down your queries) with no major benefit. Do you see any benefit?

Comment: ok. but. As a CLIENT, all objects have common attributes. I just gave the 'NAME_CODE' only. There are upto 8 common attribs for these all clients. When it is person there are some specific to Person and as a company there are some specific to Company. That's y i needed seperate table to normalize them. Otherwise I'd hv to repeat those 8 attribs for Company and Person. The classes I need are models in Business layer.

Comment: Oh I see. You're missing such a critical piece of information in the question. You will get wrong answers if you omit that. Now I understand

Comment: Why is your client id in person and bank table different from the one in original client table?

Comment: Yes Nawfal
I am sorry again Nawfal, I have to include a PersonID for person table and CompanyID for company Table. The CLIENT_ID in both table are ID from table CLIENT.

Comment: No I'm asking something different. Why is the client_id of person table different from id of client table for similar records? In other words its 1001 and 1002 in person table while in client table the id is 100 and 102!

Comment: Oh my goodness. It should be same. I will update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion, I think your tables are well designed.

I would design your tables this way:

**TABLE : CLIENT**

```
==============================
| ID   | NAME_CODE | TYPE    |
------------------------------
| 1    | Martin    | 1       |
| 2    | George    | 1       |
| 3    | Max_Group | 2       |
------------------------------
```

where `Type` is an Enum rather than anything hard-coded so that queries are faster.

**TABLE : PERSON**

```
============================================
| CLIENT_ID  | FIRST_NAME   | LAST_NAME    |
--------------------------------------------
| 1          | Martin       | XXXXXXXXXXX  |
| 2          | George       | XXXXXXXXXXX  |
--------------------------------------------
```

**TABLE : COMPANY**

```
==============================================
| CLIENT_ID  | NAME           | Location     |
----------------------------------------------
| 3          | Max Group Inc. | XXXXXXXXXXX  |
----------------------------------------------
```

And the classes would look like:

```
class Client
{
   int ID;
   string NameCode;
    //........
}

class Person : Client
{
    string FirstName;
    stirng LastName;
    //........
}

class Company : Client
{
    string Name;
    string Location;
    //.........
}
```

The Client table has the parent id now for every client entity. It could have been reversed by having individual id for persons and banks and then reference a foreign key in the parent client table which I believe is easier to operate from db point of view (that scales well if you're going for [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)). But in the application I love inheritance and polymorphism, so the straight adaptation of it for db design is what I posted.

Comment: Yes @nawfel, Its fine. I am gonna use these class structure in a Business Model. I think I can make the class 'Client' as abstract. Also I can use the class 'Client' to inject as template while testing. What do you suggest?

Comment: Yes I wanted to suggest that. Client has to be abstract since it doesn't mean anything alone. I am not thorough with testing, so I do not know