# oracle and user inputs

Tags: database, oracle

So I am kind of stuck on this Query I need to do, I have no Idea what It even means.

I need to be able to find a vehicle number from a table entitled Vehicle_Details and check whether it is currently in use for the period Of time I would like to use it as said bellow.

When a new trip is being arranged, the administrator has to find a vehicle that is not already in use for the trip duration. Because this query will be needed frequently, it is important that it can be run easily for an arbitrary start and end date. It should therefore use substitution variables so that the trip start and end dates can be provided at run time.

Make sure that when it is run the user is only prompted to supply the start and end dates once. Also make sure that any vehicles displayed are available for the entire period specified - you will have to include more than one test in the where clause

Any code would be helpful but even links to things that can help me write it myself as I have No idea tbh.

```
Example data from the three tables:
Trip_ID     Departure       Return_Date    Duration Registration
73180   07-FEB-12   08-FEB-12   1   PY09 XRH
73181   07-FEB-12   08-FEB-12   1   PY10 OPM
73182   07-FEB-12   10-FEB-12   3   PY56 BZT
73183   07-FEB-12   08-FEB-12   1   PY56 BZU
73184   07-FEB-12   09-FEB-12   2   PY58 UHF

Registration   Make          Model           Year
4585 AW        ALBION        RIEVER          1963
SDU 567M       ATKINSON      N/A             1974
P525 CAO       DAF           FT85.400        1996
PY55 CGO       DAF           FTGCF85.430     2005
PY06 BYP       DAF           FTGCF85.430     2006

Weight  Registration Body   Vehicle ID
20321   4585 AW     N/A      1
32520   SDU 567M    N/A      2
40000   P525 CAO    N/A      3
40000   PY55 CGO    N/A      4
40000   PY06 BYP    N/A      5
```

Comment: Do you have a code/query written already? Can you post the table schema/table structure here?

Comment: So is this what you mean?
Tables I will use
TRIPS table ( For the date) 
TRIP_ID
DEPARTURE
RETURN_DATE
DURATION_LENGTH
DRIVER_FIRST_NAME
DRIVER_REFERENCE
DRIVER_LAST_NAME
REGISTRATION

Vehicle details for the reg
REGISTRATION
MAKE
MODEL
YEAR

gvw(for the ID if needed)
GVW
REGISTRATION
BODY
VEHICLE_ID

Comment: I expected it to be clear like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340236/how-to-design-the-db-table-and-class) Do you have a query that you can edit your post with? the GVW is not clear either.

Comment: Sorry for the time it took IS that edit for table details any better

Comment: Is the post by Alex Poole clear to you? Otherwise let us know. I am not sure why do you need GVM table. Most probably requirement would be to have a Driver table and check if a driver is also available before assigning him to a trip.

Comment: Nvm Thanks to the link I understand it much better, Im pretty sure the guy who posted that is doing the Exact same one as me

Comment: My above comment was more on a your shcema not on the query that you want to do. I have anyway created a test. You can take a look if you wish : [query output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6e8b/9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find if a particular date range intersects with any reservation. This is interval intersection arithmetic. Consider the following intervals `[A,B]` and `[x,y]`:

```
-----------[xxxxxxxxxxx]-------------
           A           B

---------------------[xxxxxx]--------
                     x      y
```

An interval `[x,y]` will intersect with `[A,B]` if and only if:

1. `B >= x`
2. And `A <= y`

So your query will look like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM registrations reg
 WHERE reg.registration = :searched_vehicle
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM reservations res
                    WHERE res.registration = reg.registration
                      AND res.return_date >= :interval_start 
                      AND res.departure <= :interval_end)
```

This is for one vehicle. If the query returns a row, this vehicle is available for the given interval `[:interval_start, :interval_end]`.